# Stop mapkit custom MKAnnotationView disappearing on tap

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotationview

I currently have a custom MKAnnotationView set in a map callout, and it's working well. I however want to add a button to the callout view, but when i tap the button it closes the annotation view before it gets called. How can i get around this?

Here are pertinent bits of my code:
In my view for annotations:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) ->    MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "mapReuseId"
    var mapView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
    if mapView == nil {
        mapView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation as! Annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        mapView!.canShowCallout = false
    } else {
        mapView!.annotation = annotation as! Annotation
    }
    mapDottView!.image = customImage

    return mapDottView
}
```

In my didSelect delegate:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let callOut = customCallOutView(with: data)
    view.addSubview(callOut)
    // some layout here
}
```

The customCallOutView is longish, but the important part is that it has a UIButton which never gets called on tap. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a delay when your button is tapped.
You can use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch) or [Perform Selector After Delay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-performselector).

```
// Do what you need to do when your button was tapped.
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
  // Dismiss your annotation.
}
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll try that - but still not sure how to stop the dismissing of the call out on tapping of the callout.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) ->    MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "mapReuseId"
    var mapView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
    if mapView == nil {
        mapView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation as! Annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        mapView!.canShowCallout = true
        let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
        pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView
    } else {
        mapView!.annotation = annotation as! Annotation
    }
    mapDottView!.image = customImage

    return mapDottView
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    print(#function)
    // this method will be called when the button is tapped.
    // annotation view doesn't disappear
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but that won't work as I have a custom annotation view. that code just adds another standard call out over the top but doesn't fix the problem!

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't understand the meaning of your custom annotation view.